# Counting occurrences of characters in a word list

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to make an AI for a hangman game, part of which requires counting all occurrences of each possible character in the word list.  I'm planning on culling the word list before this counting to make things run faster (by first culling out all words that are not the same length as the guessable phrase, and then by culling out words that do not match the guessed characters).

The problem I am having is in the code below.  Somehow, it always returns a list of e's that are the correct length (matching the number of possible characters).  I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here, but the problem is definitely somewhere in countCharacters.

```
MethodicComputer(){
    guessable = parseGuessable();
    wordList = parseText();
    priorities = countCharacters(guessable);
}


public char guessCharacter(String hint){
    char guess = 0;
    System.out.println(guessable);
    System.out.println(priorities);
    guess = priorities.charAt(0);
    priorities = priorities.replaceAll("" + guess, "");

    return guess;
}

private String countCharacters(String possibleChars){
    charCount = new Hashtable();
    String orderedPriorities = "";
    char temp = 0;
    char adding = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int length = possibleChars.length();

    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        temp = possibleChars.charAt(i);
        count = wordList.length() - wordList.replaceAll("" + temp, "").length();
        charCount.put(temp, count);
    }

    while (orderedPriorities.length() < length){
        for (int i = 0; i < possibleChars.length(); i++){
            temp = possibleChars.charAt(i);
            if (max < (int) charCount.get(temp)){
                max = (int) charCount.get(temp);
                adding = temp;
            }
        }
        orderedPriorities += adding;
        possibleChars = possibleChars.replaceAll("" + adding, "");
    }

    return orderedPriorities;
}
```

Comment: I have done some testing on it, and found that while the replaceAll calls are weird looking, they do work (and I've changed them to a cleaner implementation of Character.toString(adding) instead of "" + adding), but am still getting a lot of e's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I did not update the max variable, so it never entered the if statement and updated the adding variable.  A simple addition of

```
max = 0;
```

to the end of the while loop fixed it.